# Jersey Client returning NullPointerException on MediaType

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, osgi, jersey-client

I have a code which sends the request to remote server to get the response. Though the response is being returned but returns NPE on below line:

```
 return (String) response.getEntity(String.class);
```

`response.getEntity`  returns NullPointerException once deployed this code on OSGI container. It works as a standalone Java Application

Following dependencies are part of the bundle:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null at
javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119) at
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getType(ClientResponse.java:695) at
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:612) at
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:586) at
io.swagger.client.ApiInvoker.invokeAPI(ApiInvoker.java:179)
```

The returned exception is as follows:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null at
>   javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119) at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getType(ClientResponse.java:695)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:612)
>   at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:586)
>   at io.swagger.client.ApiInvoker.invokeAPI(ApiInvoker.java:179)

Comment: The exception returned is java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getType(ClientResponse.java:695)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:612)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:586)
 at io.swagger.client.ApiInvoker.invokeAPI(ApiInvoker.java:179)

Comment: I think you are going to need to provide more information than this to get a meaningful/correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked once these dependencies were installed as a bundle in Felix . earlier i was trying to embed these dependencies in the bundle which was giving class loading issue while picking the actual provider implementation for services.